# In Maven, how to copy all the files in the target/surefire-reports directories to a single directory

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I have a largish Maven multiproject build.  I'm scanning the codebase with SonarQube (5.6.5).  For background, I successfully integrated the various JaCoCo exec files into SonarQube by using the "jacoco:merge" goal, to produce a single exec file.  The SonarQube property that alleges to allow specifying a list of JaCoCo exec files doesn't work in our version of SonarQube, but specifying a single one does work.

I'm now trying to integrate the numerous "TEST-*" files in "target/surefire-reports" in each of the subprojects.  The "sonar.junit.reportsPath" property expects a single directory, so I can't specify a list of them.

That means I'm going to have to do something as part of the build to merge the entire contents of all of the "target/surefire-reports" directories into a single directory, so I can specify that directory.

I already have a pom that does nothing but merge JaCoCo data.  This seems like a logical place to store the surefire reports.

How can I do this sort of thing with Maven?  Would this be an application of the "maven-resources-plugin", or something else?

Comment: Do a `mvn install` first and afterwards you can use: `mvn org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar` which will handle also multi module build perfectly...no need to handle this manually with resources copying etc....(Doing this for a 850 modules multi module build in one go)...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, well, I guess I answered my own question.  I was able to get this to work with the resources plugin, specifying every one of my modules as resource directories.  I now have one ridiculous-looking POM that has three lists of all of the modules in my multiproject build, for three tasks that require me to list all of the modules to process.  The Gradle version would be amazingly short.